# Accessing the values by their rowname and columnname,instead of numbers

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, datatable

I have a table which has multiple columns and rows. I want to access the each value by its `column name` and `rowname`, and make a plot with these values.

The table looks like this with `101 columns`:

```
IDs     Exam1  Exam2 Exam3 Exam4 .... Exam100
Ellie   12            48    33         64
Kate    98      34    21    76         
Joe     22      53    49               72        
Van     77            40    12
Xavier                      88         92
```

What I want is to be able to reach the marks for given `row` (IDs),and given `column`(exams) as:

```
table[Ellie,Exam3] --> 48
table[Ellie,Exam100] --> 64
table[Ellie,Exam2] -->     (empty)
```

Then with these numbers, I want to see the distribution of how `Ellie` did comparing the rest of exams to `Exam2`,`3` and `100`.

I have almost figured out this part with R:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
pdf("distirbution_given_row.pdf")
selectedvalues <- c(table[Ellie,Exam3] ,table[Ellie,Exam100]) 
library(plyr)
cdat <- ddply(selected values, "IDs", summarise, exams.mean=mean(exams))
selectedvaluesggplot <- ggplot(selectedvalues, aes(x=IDs, colour=exams)) + geom_density() + geom_vline(data=cdat, aes(xintercept=exams.mean, colour=IDs), linetype="dashed", size=1)
dev.off()
```

Which should generate the `Ellie'`s marks for exams of interests versus the rest of the marks ( if it is a blank, then it should not be seen as zero. It is still a blank.)

[image: Red: Marks for Exam3 and 100 and 2 , Blue: The marks for the rest 97 exams]

**Red: Marks for Exam3, 100 and 2 , Blue: The marks for the remaining 97 exams**
(The code and the plot are taken as an example of ggplot2 from [this link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_(ggplot2)/).)

All ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC - you want to plot each IDs *select* exams with *all else* exams. Consider the following steps:

1. Reshape your data to long format even replace NAs with zero as needed.
2. Run `by()` to subset data by IDs and build mean aggregrate data and ggplots.
3. Within `by`, create a *SelectValues* indicator column on the select exams then graph with vertical line mean summation.

**Data**

```
txt = 'IDs     Exam1  Exam2 Exam3 Exam4 Exam100
Ellie   12      NA      48    33         64
Kate    98      34      21    76         NA
Joe     22      53      49    NA         72        
Van     77      NA      40    12         NA
Xavier  NA      NA      NA    88         92'

exams_df <- read.table(text=txt, header = TRUE) 

# ADD OTHER EXAM COLUMNS (SEEDED FOR REPRODUCIBILITY)
set.seed(444)
exams_df[paste0("Exam", seq(5:99))] <- replicate(99-4, sample(100, 5))
```

**Reshape and Graph**

```
library(ggplot2)        # ONLY PACKAGE NEEDED

# FILL NA
exams_df[is.na(exams_df)] <- 0

# RESHAPE (BASE R VERSION)
exams_long_df <- reshape(exams_df, 
                         timevar =  "Exam", 
                         times = names(exams_df)[grep("Exam", names(exams_df))],
                         v.names = "Score",
                         varying = names(exams_df)[grep("Exam", names(exams_df))], 
                         new.row.names = 1:1000,
                         direction = "long")

# GRAPH BY EACH ID    
by(exams_long_df, exams_long_df$IDs, FUN=function(df) {

  df$SelectValues <- ifelse(df$Exam %in% c("Exam1", "Exam3", "Exam100"), "Select Exams", "All Else")

  cdat <- aggregate(Score ~ SelectValues, df, FUN=mean)

  ggplot(df, aes(Score, colour=SelectValues)) + 
    geom_density() + xlim(-50, 120) +
    labs(title=paste(df$IDs[[1]], "Density Plot of Scores"), x ="Exam Score", y = "Density") +
    geom_vline(data=cdat, aes(xintercept=Score, colour=SelectValues), linetype="dashed", size=1)

})
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am trying to reproduce. I am a bit lost in here : `exams_df[paste0("Exam", seq(5:99))] <- replicate(99-4, sample(100, 5))` . Would it mean `Exam5` to `Exam99`?

Comment: And there is no NA in the dataset..it is just empty

Comment: I am receiving an error of : `Error in if (ll[1L] != length(times)) stop("'lengths(varying)' must all match 'length(times)'") `

Comment: First, you as the OP do not need to run the data code block since you already have the data. I include it for future readers who want to test our my solution. If you copy and paste both sections in an empty R environment, the output graphs should reproduce. I just tested with zero errors.

Answer (score 2):

For accessing your data at least you can do the following:

```
df=data.frame(IDs=c("Ellie","Kate","Joe","Van","Xavier"),Exam1=c(12,98,22,77,NA),Exam2=c(NA,34,53,NA,NA),
                  Exam3=c(48,21,49,40,NA),Exam4=c(33,76,NA,12,88))

row.names(df)=df$IDs

df=df%>%select(-IDs)

> df['Joe','Exam2']
[1] 53
```

Now I prepared an example with random created numbers to illustrate a bit what you could do. First let us create an example data frame

```
df=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(505,50,10),ncol=101))
colnames(df)=c("IDs",paste0("Exam",as.character(1:100)))
df$IDs=c("Ellie","Kate","Joe","Van","Xavier")
```

To work with ggplot it is recomended to convert it to long format:

```
df0=df%>%gather(key="exams",value="score",-IDs)
```

From here on you can play with your variables as desired. For instance plotting the density of the score per ID:

```
ggplot(df0, aes(x=score,col=IDs)) + geom_density()
```

or selecting only Exams 2,3,100 and plotting density for different exams

```
df0=df0%>%filter(exams=="Exam2"|exams=="Exam3"|exams=="Exam100")
ggplot(df0, aes(x=score,col=exams)) + geom_density()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this answer would need me to write the marks for each exam, which would be 600 in total..

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you would like as a result. Could you give a sample of `selectedvalues` for instance? and maybe more data in order for your example to be reproducible. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure, `selectedvalues <- (48,64)`  ( it is actually `48,64,NA` but I cannot plot a distribution with `NA`, so if a value is a blank, then it is neglected).

Comment: I gave same samples of possible plots you might want, hope this helps!

Comment: I am trying to reproduce

Comment: It is giving an error of : `  could not find function "gather"`

Comment: install and load package `tidyr`